# expressjs put to mongo db

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

How can I put(update) data in mongo db which I receive from frontend, throught node+expressjs?

**This is my model:**

> ```
> module.exports = mongoose.model('MyData', {
>     reportData: [{
>         _id: String,
>         date: String,
>         description: String,
>         status: { type: String, default: 'new' }
>     }],
>     files: [{
>         originalname: String,
>         filename: String,
>         path: String,
>     }],    
>     author: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' } })
> ```

**This is put method:**

```
app.put('/upload/:id', bodyParser, async (req,res) => {

    var author = req.params.id;
    var report = (await MyData.find({author})).map(function(p){ return p.reportData; }).reduce(function(a, b){ return a.concat(b); }).find(x => x._id == req.body.reportId);

    report.status = req.body.event

    report.save(function(err, result){
        res.json(result);
    });

    console.log(report.status)

});
```

Currently above code return correct object with correct status, but don't save this to database.

Comment: `res.json(report)`? Maybe the language is not clear on what you are asking. You probably should also read and work out what `MyData.find({ author, 'reportData._id': req.body.reportId  },{ _id: 0, 'reportData.$': 1  })` actually does. It certainly makes things more efficient than what you are presently doing.

Comment: Even `MyData.find({ author, 'reportData._id': req.body.reportId },{ _id: 0, 'reportData.$': 1 }).cursor().map(d => d.reportData[0]._id)` if you want to get real fancy about it. That's [`Cursor.map()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/api/Cursor.html#map) BTW. Still not clear what you are asking though. But possibly ironic that you may actually be asking about positional matching, even though I was only trying to point out your `Array.find()` is really inefficient.

Comment: This MyData.find... returned something like that:      
 QueryCursor {
 ...
     op: 'find',
     options: { fields: [Object] },
     _conditions:
      { author: 5a8357e0c3188e35bc67fb29,
        'reportData._id': '5acdca1101d8b80125d7da6e' },
     _fields: { _id: 0, 'reportData.$': 1 },
     _update: undefined,
     _path: undefined,
     _distinct: undefined,
     _collection: NodeCollection { collection: [NativeCollection], collectionName: 'filedatas' },
     _traceFunction: undefined,
     _userProvidedFields: { _id: 0, 'reportData.$': 1 } },
  _transforms: [ [Function] ] }

Comment: I need only one thing -  update old value to new which I receiv from frontend. I now receive correct value and find object in which I uptade this val.

Comment: Oops! forgot the `.toArray()` Mongoose normally does that, but `.cursor()` explicitly does something else. `var report = await MyData.find({ author, 'reportData._id': req.body.reportId },{ _id: 0, 'reportData.$': 1 }).cursor().map(d => d.reportData[0]._id).toArray()`. Still don't know what you are asking though. Care to actually explain some more by adding this explanation to your question?

Comment: Yeah well there is an `.update()` method, and  a `.findOneAndUpdate()` depending on what you actually need. But nothing in your "question" as posted here actually says anything about "updating" the database or shows "by example" what you expect to happen. If you don't know the terminology, then you should show examples so we can follow. But If you don't even know about `.update()` then you really have some documentation reading to do.